# Two ASP.NET MVC applications overwrite same session cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookie-authentication, asp.net-session

I have two ASP.NET MVC applications with session configurations. When I log in from app1, that login is successful. After logging in from app2, it overwrites app1's session cookie and successfully logs in app2. But refreshing the app1 result redirects to the login page.

1. Both app1 and app2 cookie path is "/".
2. Both app1 and app2 running on the same IIS server.
3. Both app1 and app2 cookie name is unique.

I tried to change the session cookie path but it did not work.

Comment: Why can't you give them separate cookie names?

Comment: Cookie names are not the same in both app1 and app2. App1 and app2 have unique cookie names.

Comment: ...if each site's cookies have different (unique) names then they aren't overwriting "the same session cookie" - you've contradicted yourself. Please clarify.

Comment: Depends on what version of MVC you're using and how you're setting your cookie. Maybe a persistent bool is being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that by adding the cookie name to the UseCookieAuthentication pipeline in app2. Thanks everyone!

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {  
       ...
       CookieName = "Foo",
       ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your cookie http only so that way your cookie will be based on your domain like following.

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
   options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
   options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
   options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

Comment: The OP hasn't provided any details that suggest this would be a definite solution...